# Interpretation of IMU-Data for position tracking

Tags: python, ros, imu

Is it possible to track the position of an object in a reference coordinate system with an INS? if yes what is the correct approach in doing that?

Comment: Have a look at robot_localization [(doc)](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html) [(git)](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization) and read about EKF and signal processing. This topic is too large for a stack-overflow answer.

Comment: You can integrate accelerations to get position for short distances but as time goes it drifts away from real position. You'd still need some kind of global positioning system to combat drift over time. Also you want mount IMU so it would have minimal vibrations